CSS file in media folder not updated
I've installed a new theme and they have an option for customization css code.
However if you add your own css code it's storage in a file called "settings_default.css" inside pub/media folder.
Now when I've added my custom css and it's already updated in that file but on the browser nothing change!
Could you please help me how I can re generate or deploy this file inside media folder !
Because it's the first I see css file inside media folder !
I've already made hard refresh and deleted the contents of pub/static and run deploy command but it's useless.
Looking forward for your kind assistance.
Thanks in advance.

You need to let Magento style system to know that needs to consider the file you just added. See this answer for more info.
Unless the changes you are making on the site are minimal, it's better to work on your how theme to personalize the styles of the page. See the official docs or many of the tutorials on how to create a new theme an overwrite the styles correctly.

Taking for granted that the custom option is developed properly, have you checked on frontend if maybe your custom styles are there but have too little spicificity to be applied?
